# node.js global variable when inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js. I have problem in using global variable. My codes and results are below. I expected the result be 0 2 0 3 0 5 2 4 3 6 5 10 and so on because 3 child instances inherits 'parent' and each 'parent' has its 'GLOBAL' variable. But it seems that 3 child share 1 variable. Can anyone explain this situation?

---

parent.js

```
let GLOBAL = 0;


function change(num) {
    console.log("before", GLOBAL);
    GLOBAL += num;
    console.log("after", GLOBAL);

}

class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this._name = "parent"
    }

    proc() {
        change(this._num);
    }
}

module.exports = Parent;
```

child.js

```
const parent = require("./parent.js");

class Child extends parent {
    constructor(num) {
        super();
        this._num = num;
    }

    _proc() {
        this.proc(this._num);
    }
}

module.exports = Child
```

main.js

```
const child = require("./child.js");


let child2 = new child(2);
let child3 = new child(3);
let child5 = new child(5);

setInterval(() => {
    child2._proc();
    child3._proc();
    child5._proc();
}, 2000);
```

results

---

before 0
after 2
before 2
after 5
before 5
after 10
before 10
after 12
before 12
after 15
before 15
after 20
before 20
after 22
before 22
after 25
before 25
after 30
before 30
after 32
before 32
after 35
before 35
after 40
^C

Comment: this way each `Parent` share same `GLOBAL` variable because it is in outer scope of `Parent`. If you want to any `Parent` to has its own `GLOBAL`, then you'll need to put it inside his scope

Comment: Do you understand what a singleton is? If you do it's much easier to explain.

Comment: "*each 'parent' has its 'GLOBAL' variable.*" - no, what makes you think so? There is only one *global* variable `GLOBAL`. Each instance has its own `.num` and `.name` properties though.

Comment: @Bergi I think that way because each Child require Parent. But after I search [singleton in node](https://medium.com/@lazlojuly/are-node-js-modules-singletons-764ae97519af) I can understand.

Comment: @slebetman after read singleton in node, i can understand. Thanks!

Comment: @guijob actually I know how to make each child get its own global variable but I wanted to know why in this case, share global varibale. If i make child2.js, child3.js, child5.js respectively the question was clear. Thnks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're searching for is *not* a global since currently it's actually working as a global. If I understand you correctly, you want a global for each *Parent*, e.g.

```
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this._name = "parent"
        this.GLOBAL = 0;
    }

    proc() {
      console.log("before", this.GLOBAL);
      this.GLOBAL += this.num;
      console.log("after", this.GLOBAL);
    }
}

module.exports = Parent;
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I know how each Parent has GLOBAL but what i really want to know was why my code does not act I expected. But after I search singleton in node, I became know the why my result was like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because all the child instances have their own num properties but they use the same GLOBAL object when you call _proc method.

Because that you declared the GLOBAL variable on the outer scope of change function, it becomes encapsulated in the change function and won't be disposed. So anytime you call the change function, it will use the same GLOBAL variable.

As a suggestion, if you want to learn more about the topic, you can read the book Javascript, the Good Parts from Douglas Crockford.